# Error 'pack'ing nuget package in VSTS

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, azure-pipelines

I am trying to configure a new project to build and create/publish a new package using Visual Studio Team Services.  I've done this before using TFS (on-prem) and never had these kinds of issues, but I'm completely stumped on this and not even sure how to proceed with troubleshooting.

The project is fairly simple, really only has 1 class in it (for now).  It builds, unit tests run (in the build plan), but when the `NuGet Packager` task runs, I get the following output/errors:

```
******************************************************************************
Starting task: NuGet Packager
******************************************************************************
Set workingFolder to default: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.102.0\tasks\NuGetPackager\0.1.67
Executing the powershell script: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.102.0\tasks\NuGetPackager\0.1.67\NuGetPackager.ps1
tools\nuget.exe pack "C:\a\1\s\src\MyProject.Platform\MyProject.Platform.csproj" -OutputDirectory "C:\a\1\s\packages" -Properties Configuration=debug -version 0.1.0-unstable0011 -Symbols -Verbosity detailed
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'. Use option -MSBuildVersion to force nuget to use a specific version of MSBuild.
Attempting to build package from 'MyProject.Platform.csproj'.
Packing files from 'C:\a\1\s\src\MyProject.Platform\bin\Debug'.
Add file 'C:\a\1\s\src\MyProject.Platform\bin\Debug\MyProject.Platform.dll' to package as 'lib\net45\MyProject.Platform.dll'
System.InvalidOperationException: 'System.Reactive.Core' already has a dependency defined for 'System.Reactive.Interfaces'.
at NuGet.Manifest.ValidateDependencySets(IPackageMetadata metadata)
at NuGet.Manifest.Validate(Manifest manifest)
at NuGet.Manifest.ReadFrom(Stream stream, IPropertyProvider propertyProvider, Boolean validateSchema)
at NuGet.LocalPackage.ReadManifest(Stream manifestStream)
at NuGet.OptimizedZipPackage.EnsureManifest()
at NuGet.OptimizedZipPackage..ctor(IFileSystem fileSystem, String packagePath, IFileSystem expandedFileSystem)
at NuGet.SharedPackageRepository.OpenPackage(String path)
at NuGet.LocalPackageRepository.GetPackage(Func`2 openPackage, String path)
at NuGet.LocalPackageRepository.<>c__DisplayClass13.<FindPackage>b__f(String path)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at NuGet.LocalPackageRepository.FindPackage(Func`2 openPackage, String packageId, SemanticVersion version)
at NuGet.LocalPackageRepository.FindPackage(String packageId, SemanticVersion version)
at NuGet.SharedPackageRepository.FindPackage(String packageId, SemanticVersion version)
at NuGet.PackageRepositoryExtensions.FindPackage(IPackageRepository repository, String packageId, SemanticVersion version, IPackageConstraintProvider constraintProvider, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions, Boolean allowUnlisted)
at NuGet.CommandLine.ProjectFactory.<>c__DisplayClass92_0.<AddFiles>b__0(PackageReference reference)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__16`2.MoveNext()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at NuGet.CommandLine.ProjectFactory.AddFiles(PackageBuilder builder, String itemType, String targetFolder)
at NuGet.CommandLine.ProjectFactory.<>c__DisplayClass56_0.<CreateBuilder>b__1(ProjectFactory p)
at NuGet.CommandLine.ProjectFactory.ApplyAction(Action`1 action)
at NuGet.CommandLine.ProjectFactory.CreateBuilder(String basePath)
at NuGet.CommandLine.PackCommand.BuildFromProjectFile(String path)
at NuGet.CommandLine.PackCommand.BuildPackage(String path)
at NuGet.CommandLine.PackCommand.ExecuteCommand()
at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.ExecuteCommandAsync()
at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.Execute()
at NuGet.CommandLine.Program.MainCore(String workingDirectory, String[] args)
System.Exception: Unexpected exit code 1 returned from tool nuget.exe
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.PowerShell.InvokeToolCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
******************************************************************************
Finishing task: NuGetPackager
******************************************************************************
```

I've done just about everything I can think to troubleshoot this, including cloning the repo fresh to my local machine with the exact same paths (`C:\a\1\s`) and including the version of nuget from my machine (v3.4.3) in the repo so that the nuget task can use that specific version.  When I run the exact command line from the log locally, it creates the package with no problems.

In the VSTS build it seems to choke on `System.Reactive` dependency for some unknown reason.  I've even marked that dependency with `developmentDependency="true"` to see if that made any difference, but it seems like `nuget.exe` is ignoring the `packages.config` file entirely.

Below is an image of the task configuration, it's pretty straight-foward:

[image: Task config]

Comment: I have the same problem with Jenkins and Subversion. What Version of Nuget.exe you use?

Comment: @GreenEyedAndy I have tried several versions of `nuget.exe` including the most recent (as of the original post), it didn't make any difference which version I used.

Comment: thank you for the response. I just want to ask since I havn't found a solution yet. I also tried different nuget versions, for me the 3.4.4 is solving my problem with system.reactive, but it handles the update-packages command different to v2.x - so I can't use this either.